# Can an enum-variable ever assume a value not defined in the enum?

Tags: c#, enums

In the following code-snippet, can the inside of the `if` ever be reached, if yes, under which circumstances?

```cs
MyEnum foo = ...;

if(!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), foo))
{
    // reachable?
}
```

---

I have a WebController which expects a `MyEnum` as Parameter. This parameter is then given to a Service, with the given check. Now I wonder how that check could ever be false, given that `foo` needs to be a value from `MyEnum` or an `ArgumentException` at an earlier point (e.g. if the user provided an illegal argument).

The code definitely uses a variable of type `MyEnum`, not a `string` or `int`.

Comment: Read the [documentation for Enum.IsDefined()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.isdefined?view=net-5.0).  It says: *"Returns a Boolean telling whether a given integral value, or its name as a string, exists in a specified enumeration."*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's reachable. For example:

```
public enum MyEnum { Foo = 1 }
```

// ...

```
MyEnum foo = (MyEnum)9999;

if (!Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MyEnum), foo))
{
    Console.Write("reachable");
}
```

Comment: Why can you do this? (Question obviously not directed at you.) I have only ever assigned Enum-Values to my variables, not casted integers. So much for that. Thank you.

Comment: @JFBM: Its common that you cast integers to an enum type. If that integer comes from an external system it would be a good idea to use `Enum.IsDefined` first. It's always possible that someone changes those integers which might break such casts without a compiler error.